# How to handle onClick or onTouch event in my custom class?

Tags: java, android

I have a custom class MyFloatingButton which inherits nothing. I'd like to handle onClick or onTouch event in it. How to do it?
The constructor function receives context, activity and view from activity:

```
public MyFloatingButton(Context context, RootActivity activity, View view) {
        this.context = context;
        this.activity = activity;
        this.activityView = view;
        getViews();
        initCircleSelector();
    }
private void getViews() {

        floatingActionButton = (FloatingActionButton) activityView.findViewById(R.id.btn_publish);
        circle_selector = (FrameLayout) activityView.findViewById(R.id.circle_selector);
        selector_text = (LinearLayout) activityView.findViewById(R.id.selector_text_div);
        shade_cover = (FrameLayout) activityView.findViewById(R.id.shade_cover);
    }
```

I tried doing the same things in class MyFloatingButton as it's an Activity. But it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to do it is to implement a click listener and then set it to the View in the constructor.

Example:

```
public MyFloatingButton implements View.OnClickListener {

    public MyFloatingButton(Context context, RootActivity activity, View view) {
        this.context = context;
        this.activity = activity;
        this.activityView = view;
        getViews();
        initCircleSelector();
        activityView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        // handle click event
    }

    .....

}
```

Do the same for OnTouch

Comment: Do you mean that we can do the same as what we do in an Activity to response onClick event? But it doesn't work... Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: It does work. OnClickListener is an interface, if you set it to a View and handle it, it will work. Try out the code I just gave you and handle the onClick event

Answer (score 0):

Your custom class should extend the class "View" in order to have access to the method onClick and onTouch

In my opinion it's better to extend the class ["FloatingActionButton"](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton)

Those methods are implemented in the class View. So in order for you to have access, your class have to inherit View or anything I showed you.